# Notepad++ - Effective handling of groups of tags

Tags: notepad++

What I want:

A menu entry in which I can add something like workspaces, where every workspace saves it's tabs automatically. So that I can fastly switch between a set of opened tabs via that menu.

Does anything like this exist?

Answer (score 0):

#### I want to fast switch between a set of opened tabs via that menu.

This already built in to Notepad++ as [Sessions](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Sessions_And_Projects).

You can use:

- Menu "File" > "Load session..."
- Menu "File" > "Save session..."

> [image]

---

#### [Sessions And Projects](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Sessions_And_Projects)

> **How to store and retrieve sets of files as they were opened in Notepad++**
>
> Sessions keep track of what files are opened in Notepad++, with some
>   extra information like file positions and highlighter for the file.
>   The detailed contents of session files is described in the relevant
>   section of Editing Configuration Files.
>
> Sessions do not backup files - see "Settings" -> "Preferences" ->
>   "Backup/Auto-Completion" about this.
>
> There are exactly 5 controls in Notepad++ that relate to sessions:
>
> - "File" > "Load session...."
> - "File" > "Save session...."
> - "Settings" > "Preferences" > "Backup" > "Remember current session for next launch"
> - "Settings" > "Preferences" > "Backup" > "Enable session snapshots and periodic backups"
> - "Settings" > "Preferences" > "MISC" > "Session file ext.:"
>
> This page is about using sessions to manage projects (see Project
>   Management) because it is their main use and because, before version
>   5.9.4, it was the only available tool.
>
> **Start a new project**
>
> Open all existing file that are to be on the project. You can plan for
>   the future by adding a few new files you expect to have contents soon.
>   Click "File" > "Save session", and save to some session file.
>
> If you have some foresight, create a project folder first, and then
>   save the current session. We'll see later how this can be useful.
>
> **Add/Remove**
>
> Open Notepad++, then click "File" > "Load session". Choose your session
>   file. Now either open the file to be added, or close file to be
>   removed. "File" > "Save session", you are done. By the way, the last
>   current session is remembered in `<Notepad++.exe folder>\session.xml`.
>
> **Session files**
>
> They are plain xml files, with some obvious structure you can borrow
>   from existing session. This means you can edit them manually, if this
>   is easier. In particular, session files will record bookmarks and how
>   text is folded.
>
> By default, session files have the .xml extension, but you can change
>   that from "Settings" > "Preferences" > "MISC" > "Session file ext" (look in
>   the lower right corner).
>
> `session.xml` does not get renamed when you change the default session
>   extension. This is not an issue, because you can ask Notepad++ to load
>   any file, as long as it has contents that can be understood.