# How can I organize files opened in notepad++ by project

Tags: notepad++

I usually have 20 or so pages open in Notepad++ and would like to somehow group the related files together so that I can more easily navigate between them.

I've read about the Project feature in Notepad++ but I'm not sure it's what I need. I don't want to list all of the file in a folder as a project. The files that I need to group together are not in the same folder, and I don't want to list or open all of the files in any folder.

One solution to this would work something like this:

- There is a sidebar for "workgroups"
- I can create and rename and otherwise manage the workgroups
- I can associate any open file/tab with a workgroup
- When I close a file it is automatically removed from the workgroup

If I were to dream about how ideally it might work, there would be a way to specify that any open file that is a under a specified root folder would automatically be added to that workgroup.

Comment: Are you trying to learn how to add this capability to Notepad++, or how to find whether Notepad++ already has this feature?

Comment: I'd like to know how to exploit the existing capabilities of npp or one of it's plugins to solve the need...my ending paragraph was simply a visualization of something that would work for me.

Answer (score 0):

There is no capability such as you describe in Notepad++.

There is a feature request from 3 years ago asking for something similar: https://notepad-plus-plus.org/community/topic/11573/feature-request-tab-groups-and-guidence

There are no comments or responses on the feature request.

There are a few other questions asking similar or related things, and based on reading those there do not seem to be features in this application such as you describe:

[Is there a way to manage tabs efficiently in Notepad++](https://superuser.com/questions/153109/is-there-a-way-to-manage-tabs-efficiently-in-notepad)

[Notepad++ - Effective handling of groups of tags](https://superuser.com/questions/1117095/notepad-effective-handling-of-groups-of-tags)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6108193/notepad-show-open-files-on-the-left

Comment: I'd see most of those posts, was hoping there was something I'd missed. Too bad.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

- From the view menu -> Project -> Project Panel 1
- At this point, you should have a new window the left of your main window.
- I don't recall if you have to, first, save the psuedo-workspace file.  If so,
  do so.
- Then Right click on the workspace node and choose 'Add New
  Project'.  Give it a name.
- Then Right click on the project node and choose 'Add Files' or 'Add Folders' for that matter.

You can mix and match files and folders from separate directories easily into each project node.  Don't forget to save.